# Dropbox create a folder using PHP without cURL

Tags: php, dropbox-api

I am following this tutorial http://fabi.me/en/php-projects/dropphp-dropbox-api-client/.

I managed to authenticate the app using the sample.php and tested it using the sample.php

Now I am trying to create a folder using the SDK but I do not know how to go about it. At points 2 and 3 the code seems garbled.

I tried this till now:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once("DropboxClient.php");


$dropbox = new DropboxClient(array('app_key' => "YOUR_APP_KEY",
'app_secret'=> "YOUR_APP_SECRET",'app_full_access' => false,),'en'); 


$this->apiCall("fileops/create_folder", "POST", array('root' => , 'path' => ));
?>
```

I obviously changed YOUR_APP_KEY and YOUR_APP_SECRET with my own for security reasons.

I can't manage to create the folder / directory. Is there something wrong in my php code?

Comment: I updated my question _I can't manage to create the folder / directory._ I have a problem in the code it seems.

Comment: Can you make `CreateFolder($path)` ? And you have openSSL activated? `extension=php_openssl.dll` in php.ini?

Comment: I tried but id din;t upload. I think there must be something wrong in my code.

Comment: powtac and I want you to provide detailed error info.

Comment: If you provide the actual error you get, I will up your question one.

Comment: _PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ',' in  on line 11_ That is the error that it is giving me.

Answer (score 0):

Try add `curl_setopt($context, CURLOPT_UPLOAD,1);`

If you are on VPS do `I removed the 1.1.0 (sudo pecl uninstall oauth), than downloaded 1.0.0 from the oauth page and built oauth.so from source, and since then everything work.`;

For DropPHP disable cURL as:
`$myDropPHP->SetUseCurl(false);`

If you didn't sure why isn't work try dump a data as simple:

```
$dump = $this->apiCall("fileops/create_folder", "POST", array('root' => , 'path' => ));
var_dump($dump); exit;
```

This will go to you for find why is error or not working...
Or view on log PHP file for errors (tail -f /var/log/error.log)

Or... https://serverfault.com/questions/485285/install-oauth-extension-for-php-in-debian-wheezy

Try using DROPBOX PEAR: http://pear.dropbox-php.com/

You can instead of this fix, use DROPBOX PHP API client: http://www.dropbox-php.com/

This code you have it's maybe outdated or conflicted with some library for an older version (worked) but on newer not solved. This needs manually change in code. Use DROPBOX PHP API client on above link and tell if it's worked.

I found a Dropbox API on Codecanyon look at simple YT link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3Gy5Ci3sog

Comment: I wish to create it without cURL.

Comment: DropPHP uses cURL by default, if cURL is installed. You must call `$myDropPHP->SetUseCurl(false);` to not use cURL.

Comment: DropPHP hasn't been updated in 2 months, the exact URL to create a folder and post variables needed may have changed. If I was you I would just use curl and keep the url's and post variables current myself. To get the right URL and vars needed use a program like Fiddler: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/